# QML table view Image as cell element

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to display Image and Text in a row of QML table view component, I chose itemDelegate to accomplish it, but the result shows as the bold text on each row, and in image column both image and text are displayed. It seems two times the model items are displaying on the table.

Code:

```
Rectangle{
        width:parent.width
        height:parent.height
        color: "#333333"
        id: root


    ListModel {
        id: live_alertmodel

    }

    TableView {
       // anchors.top: download_bt.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: root.width
        height: 100

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "time"
            title: "Time"
            width: root.width/4
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            role: "location"
            title: "Location"
            width: root.width/4
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "alert"
            title: "Alert"
            width: root.width/4
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "image"
            title: "Image"
            width: root.width/4

        }
        model: live_alertmodel

       itemDelegate: Item {
            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color: styleData.textColor
                //elide: styleData.elideMode
                text: styleData.value
            }

            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color: styleData.textColor
                //elide: styleData.elideMode
                text: styleData.value
            }

            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                color: styleData.textColor
                //elide: styleData.elideMode
                text: styleData.value
                font.bold: false
            }

            Image {
                id: myIcon;
                width:root.width/4;
                //height:50;
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
                source: styleData.value;
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                height:20
                cache : true;
                asynchronous: true;
            }
       }


        Component.onCompleted: {
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
              live_alertmodel.append({ time:"12/15/2015",
                              location:"location",
                              alert:"access",
                              image:"http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/previews/4852/48521810-globe-icon-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" })
        }
    }
    }
```

Also see the screen shot how the out put looks with the above code.

[image]

Anything wrong with above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it by

1. Removing `itemDelegate` from `TableView`
2. Defining `delegate` item for each `TableViewColumn` like,

   ```
   TableViewColumn {
       role: "time"
       title: "Time"
       width: root.width/4
       delegate:textDelegate
   }
   TableViewColumn {
       role: "location"
       title: "Location"
       width: root.width/4
        delegate:textDelegate
   }
   TableViewColumn {
       role: "alert"
       title: "Alert"
       width: root.width/4
       delegate:textDelegate
   }

   TableViewColumn {
       role: "image"
       title: "Image"
       width: root.width/4
       delegate:imageDelegate
   }
   ```
3. Finally created separate delegate item for text and image column

   ```
    Component  {
                   id: textDelegate
                   Item {
                       id: f_item
                       height: cell_txt.height
                       Text {
                           id: cell_txt
                           width: parent.width
                           verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                           horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                           //font.bold: true
                           text: styleData.value
                           elide: Text.AlignHCenter
                           color: "white"
                           renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                       }
                   }
               }


   Component {
       id: imageDelegate
       Item {
           Image {
               anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
               anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
               fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
               height:20
               cache : true;
               asynchronous: true;
               source: styleData.value// !== undefined  ? styleData.value : ""
           }
       }
    }
   ```